Manga were the main character has a tiger for a master and uses nature magic
I'm looking for this manga where the protagonist lives in an outlaw world. I believe the good guys are called exorcists. The main character has a master, a tiger, who is one of the strongest called outlaws. The main character is special because he uses a power called nature.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.
